# How can I recursively print a File Array?

Tags: java, recursion

I would like to know how to recursively print a File[]. I have made a program but it seems that the program is going out of bounds and I don't know how to fix it. Can someone please give me a few pointers or hints on how to solve this problem? Thanks.

```
import java.io.*;

public class RecursiveDir {

static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException {
    System.out.print("Please enter a directory name: ");
    File f = new File(br.readLine());

    FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() {

        public boolean accept(File f) {
            if(f.isDirectory()) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    };

    File[] list = f.listFiles(filter);
    System.out.println(returnDir(list,list.length));
}

public static File returnDir(File[] file,int counter) {
    File f = file[counter];
    if(counter == 0) {
        return file[0];
    }else {
        return f = returnDir(file,counter--);
    }
}
}
```

EDIT: I followed the comments below and changed `return f = returnDir(file,counter--);` to 
`return f = returnDir(file,--counter);` and also changed `returnDir(list,list.length);` to
`returnDir(list,list.length-1);`, my code runs fine but now nothing is printing.

Comment: What were you expecting to be printed?  I don't see any output statements in your code.

Comment: Also, for clarity, it is better to do this:
`counter--; return returnDir(file, counter);`

Comment: i need to recursively print the absolute paths of the file.

Comment: Are you supposed to go down each subdirectory too?

Comment: no. so for example, if I type C:/ then it should print all the directories in C:/

Comment: You might want to expand each recursive call. Write out the exact sets of arguments. I think you will find that the call to System.out.println needs to be inside the recursive function

Comment: I don't understand why you need recursion for this then, if you're not going into subdirectories.  File.list() gives you all you need - you just need to iterate over the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going out of the array bound because you need to pass `list.length - 1` to the method.

Even if you did that, though, you would have an infinite recursion, because `counter--` will use the value of counter, and then decrement it. So that means you are calling `returnDir` with the current value of `counter.` Use either `--counter`, or `counter - 1`.

Comment: That's why I always avoid prefix and postfix operators in expressions.  It can muddy the code, as the poster discovered.

Answer (score 2):

What do expect to happen here? You don't seem to be doing anything with the files as you visit them. There is no need for recursion to loop through the files in the directory, the recursion is needed when you hit a file in the list that *is* a directory.

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed going out of bounds. You need to change

```
returnDir(list,list.length);
```

to

```
returnDir(list,list.length - 1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing your System.out.println() calls. You are looping through the files and not doing anything with them.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial call to returnDir should be

```
returnDir(list,list.length-1);
```

Paul